# Create a redirect and response error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

im managing the authorization of some somes, and one of them i wish toe give a 403 and also redirect the user but isnt working, isnt redirecting to the dashboard

My example code is:

```
 protected function unauthorized()
    {
         abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
         return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `abort()` method in Laravel throws an `app()->abort()` call, which throws an `\Exception` depending on which code you've supplied:

```
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    if ($code == 404) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
    }

    throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
}
```

You can consume this exception in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
     if ($e instanceof HttpException ) {
         return redirect('/dashboard')->withErrors([
              'message' => 'You are not allowed to access that portion of the site.'
         ]);
     }
}
```

Of course you may need to add further logic to the conditional to check for things such as an actually authorized user. For unauthorized users, you may wish to redirect them to the login page instead. You can observe that with a simple `if (auth()->check()) { }else { }`.

Comment: This is probably the right thing to do but it doesn't actually return a 403 response although I can't imagine that's important because it's redirecting anyway.  Mine as well just `return redirect('/dashboard');` and save ourselves from having to write a handler for those exceptions which don't need to be generated in the first place.

Comment: @user3158900 Yes, you're right. I took the liberty of making some assumptions about what the OP wants given his request .This could easily return a 403 if it's absolutely required.